# build Drone using Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, drone.io

I have searched in all hub.docker images to find a good Dockerfile to build my own custom CI drone.io server container.

I found some of them but some have errors or don't work.

I found this link to download http://downloads.drone.io/master/drone.deb but it is and old version of drone.io.

Any idea where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the open source version, you should be able to use the Dockerfile provided on Github. The current release is v0.4.2, the file for which can be found here: https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/v0.4.2/Dockerfile

You can also get the automatically built images here:
https://hub.docker.com/r/drone/drone/tags/ I would recommend version 0.4 as 0.4.2 still has a few DNS issues.

(See http://readme.drone.io/setup/overview/ for the full setup walkthrough)